# Check and validate if a certain number starting with a certain value is available

Tags: c#, .net, string, logic, contains

I want to check between two values as to if they have a relation . For example I have the following code ,

```
string valuee = "2.5";

string otherValue = "2.5.5.0";

if (valuee.Contains(otherValue))
{}
```

since the other value variable has the "2.5" part of the valuee  variable , I want the if clause to be true to proceed with the rest of the logic

I tried with the contains method and the starts with method , both which gives false ?

Does anyone know how I can implement this behavior ?

Comment: Reverse checking: `otherValue.Contains(valuee)` instead of `valuee.Contains(otherValue)`

Comment: `valuee.Contains(otherValue)` asks "does "2.5" contain "2.5.5.0"? - it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check only if first value contains second. You also need to perform the opposite:

```
if (valuee.Contains(otherValue) || otherValue.Contains(valuee))
```

Comment: wow , I have no idea how this logic works but it does the job . If you dont mind can you explain a bit please

Comment: I as said in the answer, you check only if first value contains second, ie 2.5 contains 2.5.5.0, which is false obviously as first value does not have even such a length. So you need to check if second value contains first, i.e 2.5.5.0 contains 2.5, which is true. And to be logic universal that does not depend on which value is master and which is secondary, there is “or” statement in “if” clause that checks both

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the wrong variable

```
    if (otherValue.Contains(valuee))
    {}
```